# How to load huge time series windows dataset without memory errors?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I want to convert a typical time series dataset of about 1 million lines into 100-item windows with 50% overlap. Note that it's a multivariate one, so for example given 8 features and 1000 windows with 100 items the final shape would be `(1000, 100, 8)` replacing `(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)`. The goal is to use it for training machine learning algorithms including deep neural networks.

So far, I've enjoyed using numpy's `sliding_window_view` as shown below;

```
x = np.arange(100).reshape(20, 5)
v = sliding_window_view(x, (3, 5))
v
```

Unfortunately, I get crashes as I run out of RAM in large datasets with millions of lines. Do you have any suggestion?

Additionally, one serious restriction is that there's a consecutive label for every timestep (integer) according to which the dataset needs to be grouped by (using `pandas`) so this limits some options about reading it in portions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `tf.data.Dataset`. I'm working on a million rows dataset, and the following code runs well for me:

```
convert = tf.data.TextLineDataset("path_to_file.txt")
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(convert)
```

Now you have initialized your dataset, but for don't stepping into memory issues:

```
def dataset_batches(ds, batch_size):
  return (
      ds
      .cache()
      .batch(batch_size)
      .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE) )
      # you can do more operations here

train_batches = dataset_batches(dataset, 64)
```

And to run it, you'll have to loop:

```
for (batch, row) in enumerate(train_batche):
   # do stuff
   # batch = current batch (0, 1, 2, ...) so if your dataset has 1600 rows and you've used batch_size=16 you'll have 100 batches
   # row is the actual data (tensor)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when you need to produce sliding windows and shuffle them afterwards?